# Pass QModelIndex instead of QString when QCompleter highlighted

Tags: qt, pyqt, qcompleter, qmodelindex

There is a QCompleter (set to QLineEdit) populated with QStandardItemModel. That model also populates the QTableView, I need to get the QModelIndex and select it in QTableView but it fails, it
passes text instead of QModelIndex:

```
completer.highlighted.connect(print_index)
```

passes only the first index:

```
completer.highlighted.connect(lambda : select_index(completer.currentIndex()))

def select_index(index):

    table_view.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

I read docs, but cannot understand what do I do wrong.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#highlighted-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two versions of the [`highlighted` signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcompleter.html#highlighted): the default one emits a string, the other emits a `QModelIndex`
To get the index, use:

```
completer.highlighted[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(onHighlight)
```

But be careful, this is the index in the [completion model](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcompleter.html#completionModel), not the model you populated the completer with. You can use `mapToSource` to get the original index.

```
def onHighLight(index):
    #completer model
    print(index)
    #model 
    sourceIndex=completer.completionModel().mapToSource(index)
    print(sourceIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use `row()` function of `QmodelIndex`. It will directly return the list index of your current selection.